# Sass is not found after creating a new Vue app and adding lang="sass" to some styles

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite

This is the current Sass version installed:

```
> sass --version
1.62.1 compiled with dart2js 2.19.6
```

Yet if I start the vue application with `npm run dev` and open the app url I get

```
Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?
18:47:19 [vite] Internal server error: Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?
  Plugin: vite:css
```

In the browser I see:

```
[plugin:vite:css] Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?
```

But Sass runs just fine. How do I enable Sass in Vue successfully? The app was created with `npm init vue@latest`.

I used to have node-sass installed but removed it

Answer (score 1):

You must link SASS with the compiler, to do this you need to add sass-loader in your project.

```
npm i -D sass-loader
```

Personally I prefer to install SASS as a local dependency, because you'll have more control over the version of this library, specially for "old" projects (today projects, old in maybe 5 or more years).

Comment: thanks. The scaffolding was created with init. Are the steps you describe required after the init?